# apply function to Pandas dataframe with index as argument

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I made a function that takes one single argument, but now I want to apply it to a whole dataframe where the index is the argument. My first impulse is to do a for loop but I know those are frowned upon in Pandas.

I have some data from the World Bank API, in a dataframe "df" for many countries and years:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|                             ODA  gdp_per_cap   sant    mort |
| country     date                                            |
| Afghanistan 2010 6235319824.219       11.264 34.177  87.600 |
|             2009 6113120117.188       18.515 32.910  91.400 |
|             2008 4811209960.938        1.594 31.655  95.400 |
|             2007 4982609863.281       11.023 30.412  99.500 |
|             2006 2895830078.125        2.253 29.181 103.700 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The country and date are indexes. I need create a new dataframe and populate it with calculations. The new dataframe has the same country index but no date.

I wrote this function to calculate some fields:

```
def fill_df(country):
    total_oda = bil(df.loc[country, 'ODA'].sum()/10)
    gdp = df.loc[country, 'gdp_per_cap'].mean()
    sanitation = percent_change(country, 'sant')
    mortality = percent_change(country, 'mort')
    metric = (-pow(total_oda, .5) + gdp/4 + sanitation*.5 - mortality*0.5 + 80)*.2
    final_df.loc[country] = [total_oda, gdp, sanitation, mortality, metric]

fill_df('Afghanistan')
fill_df('Burundi')
```

Ok so the function works for one country at a time. This is the new final_df:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|                             ODA   gdp   sant    mort metric |
| country                                                     |
| Afghanistan               3.329 6.606 45.293 -29.695 23.464 |
| Burundi                   0.392 0.236  1.115 -39.439 19.942 |
| Burkina Faso                NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN    NaN |
| Central African Republic    NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN    NaN |
| Congo, Dem. Rep.            NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN    NaN |
| Eritrea                     NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN    NaN |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now I want to apply it to all final_df. Below is the idea, but does not work because my function takes one argument instead of an index of values.

```
country_idx = df.index.get_level_values(0).unique()
final_df.apply(fill_df, axis=0, args=country_idx)
```

How to apply the function to final_df?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use `groupby(country)`, and apply your aggregating function to each group? You would make `df` the parameter of your `fill_df` (which also does away with `df` being a global variable in your code). Then just apply `fill_df` to each group: `df.groupby('country').apply(lambda gr: fill_df(gr))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `agg` on `level=0` argument

```
final_df = df.groupby(level=0).agg((
              total_oda = ('ODA', lambda x: x.sum()/10),
              gdp = ('gdp_per_cap', 'mean'),
              sanitation = ('sant', percent_change),
              mortality = ('mort', percent_change),
              metric = (-pow(total_oda, .5) + gdp/4 + sanitation*.5 - mortality*0.5 + 80)*.2
))
```